# Adding a custom item to a Silverlight ComboBox bound to ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a search screen within my application that has a ComboBox which is bound to an ObservableCollection in a ViewModel (the collection contains Organisation entities returned via WCF from an Entity Framework model).

I wish to add an item to the combo representing "All Organisations" - so the user does not have to specify an organisation when searching.

Is there a way of adding custom items to a ComboBox or do I have to add a dummy Organisation to the collection and carry out the necessary logic when this is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WPF combo box, adding an all options item, when binding to an Observable Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619032/wpf-combo-box-adding-an-all-options-item-when-binding-to-an-observable-collecti).  It describes one option which is a [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx).